# Use of attribute 'for' to link a custom element

Tags: html, accessibility, forms

I had created a jQuery plugin which transform a form HTML like this

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_01" value="1"/>
    <label for="chexkbox_01"></label>
</form>
```

Into a form like that:

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_01" value="1" aria-hidden="true" />
    <span role="checkbox" id="aria-checkbox_01" aria-checked="false" tabindex="0"></span>
    <label for="aria-chexkbox_01"></label>
<form>
```

Is it valid to change the `for` attribute to link a custom element?

Comment: set <label for="checkbox_01"></label> to link your input element.Is that you want?

Comment: No i want keep te native checkbox to store the user response, but i want use a stylisable (the sapn) element has an interface.

Comment: Sorry : No i want keep the native checkbox to store the user response, but i want use a stylisable element (the span) as an interface.

Answer (score 4):

No.

> If the attribute is specified, the attribute's value must be the ID of a labelable element in the same Document as the label element.

— https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-label-for

> Some elements, not all of them form-associated, are categorized as labelable elements. These are elements that can be associated with a label element.
>
> button input (if the type attribute is not in the hidden state) keygen meter output progress select textarea

— https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#category-label

A span is not a labelable element.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to test your code.

As you can see, the `for` attribute lost his fonctionnality, if you click on the label, the checkbox is not selected.

So you must have same `for` and `id` attribute in your `label/input`

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_01" value="1" aria-hidden="true" />
<span role="checkbox" id="aria-checkbox_01" aria-checked="false" tabindex="0"></span>
<label for="aria-chexkbox_01">Click on label must check the checkbox</label>
```

Comment: Thanks Alexis, i made this change because of the aria-hidden attribut of the checkbox, the focus was made by javascript on click on label. I must rethink my plugin...

Comment: Nota : The problem here is not really that clicking the label does not check the non native checkbox (which can perfectly be done using a script), but the fact that focusing this `role=checkbox` element does not retrieve the accessible description of the element.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `aria-labelledby` to achieve what you want:

```
<form>
<span role="checkbox" aria-labelledby="aria-label" aria-checked="false" tabindex="0"></span>
<span id="aria-label">Label</label>
</form>
```

The `label` element is reserved to some native form elements:

> `button` `input` (if the type attribute is not in the hidden state) `keygen` `meter` `output` `progress` `select` `textarea`